# Issue in macro to print size and range of integers

Tags: c

How to write a macro to print size and range of any integer data type without using sizeof operator. Can you please let me know, how to procede?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show what did you try?

Comment: printf("The size of integer is %d\n", sizeof(int));

Comment: Do you know the difference between a macro and a regular function?

Comment: Sorry, I meant without using sizeof operator. Editing my question.

Comment: How to proceed: - Investigate what you want to do - Codify something that may give you what you want - Ask on SO if any doubt arises

Comment: @KingJohnno: `%zu`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think following macro should help you.

```
#define RANGE(type, name)  \ 
{ \ 
               type min=0, max=0, bit=0; \
                unsigned int bits=0; \
                 char *format;  \
                 \
                 /* measure size of data type in bits */ \
                 bits=1; \
                 bit=1; \
                 while(bit <<= 1) bits++; \
                  \
                 /* signed or unsigned */  \
                 if((type)(1L << (bits-1)) > 0) \
                 {  \
                                 format = "%lu"; /* unsigned */ \
                                 min = 0; \
                 } \
                 else \
                 { \
                                 format = "%ld"; /* signed */ \
                                 min = (type) (1L << (bits - 1)); \
                 } \
                 \
                 max = min - 1;  /* roll over backwards */ \
                 printf("%s, %u bits : Range from ", name, bits); \
                 printf(format , (long)min); \
                 printf(" to "); \
                 printf(format , (long)max); \
                 printf("\n"); \
 }
```

Parameters of the macro are 
1) Any integer data type
2) Name of data type in string format

For example

```
RANGE(unsigned int, "unsigned int");
```

Comment: Yes, I fulfills my expectations. Thanks!